# CSS: Collapse - Removing overflow: hidden when open

Tags: html, css

I currently have implemented the following collapsable div :

```
.my-collapse {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all .3s ease;
}

.my-collapse.is-open {
   max-height: 2000px;
}
```

It works fine, however, my opened collapsable div has `overflow: hidden` which isn't useful at all.
I can't applied a `transition-delay` on the `overflow` property and I need the overflow to be hidden as long as the div isn't fully open.
Any idea how can I get rid of this property **without** any js ?

Comment: You can use visibility: visible/hidden with transition.

Comment: try to use `visibility: visible` when using transition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `clip-path` which *can* be transitioned.

> The clip-path CSS property creates a clipping region that sets what part of an element should be shown. Parts that are inside the region are shown, while those outside are hidden.
>
> [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.toggle {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 1em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: lightgrey;
}

.toggle:hover+.my-collapse {
  max-height: 2000px;
  clip-path: inset(0px 0px 0px 0px)
}

.my-collapse {
  max-height: 0;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 1em;
  clip-path: inset(0 0 100% 0px)
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle">Hover Me</div>

<div class="my-collapse">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima, eos ea, quis corporis dicta blanditiis vero eius neque ipsa maiores veritatis earum. Magni, veniam cupiditate.</p>
</div>
```